# cos(z) is surjective for set S

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)=cos(z)$ and $S=\{z \in \mathbb{C} | 0<Im(z), 0<Re(z)< \pi\}.$ Show that $f(z)$ is injective on $S$ and that $f(\bar{S})=\mathbb{C}$.

For injectivity I used $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$ what lead me to the equation $(u-w)(1-\frac{1}{uw})=0$ with $u=e^{iz_1},w=e^{iz_2}$ and I was able to see that $z_1=z_2$.

What I'm having problems with is the second part:

Let $w\in \mathbb{C}$ with $f(z)=w$. I now need to show that $z \in \bar{S}$.

With $u=e^{iz}$

$w=\frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz}) \Rightarrow 2wu=u^2+1 \Rightarrow u_{1/2}=\frac{2w \pm \sqrt{4w^2-4}}{2}$

However, I am stuck here.

Edit:

$u_{1/2}=\frac{2w \pm \sqrt{4w^2-4}}{2}\Rightarrow 2e^{iRe(z)}e^{-Im(z)}=2w \pm \sqrt{4w^2-4}\Rightarrow 2e^{-Im(z)}=|2w \pm \sqrt{4w^2-4}|\Rightarrow Im(z) = -ln(\frac{|2w \pm \sqrt{4w^2-4}|}{2})$

In order for $z$ to be out of $S$ we need $-ln(\frac{|2w \pm \sqrt{4w^2-4}|}{2})$ to be positive. How can I see this?

Comment: Hint: Surjective means that you for all w there is a z such that f(z) = w. If you can find a z for all w, that solves the problem.

Comment: The problem I'm having is showing that said z is in S.

Comment: For logarithm of a quantity to be negative, you need the quantity to be less than 1. Solve that inequality.